# Creating a loop that fades out each article in succession. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the idea is to fade each image out from the bottom.. obviously it's going to have to backwardly traverse the array. However, i can't seem to figure it out at the moment. The idea is that it would pause after running the fadeOut() function, I thought set time out would work, but firebug gives me this error:
useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)

Line 262.
I even went as far as to not use a $.each loop and use a for (i=0 loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Bottom Nav functions
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#bottomNav a:eq(0)').click(function(){

        var arti = $('#aHolder article');
        var amt = arti.length;
        var i = 0;

            for (i=0;i<amt;i++){

            $('#aHolder article:eq('+i+')').fadeOut();
            setTimeout(300);

            }


        });

    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
var i = $('#aHolder article').length,
interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (i-- <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    $('#aHolder article:eq(' + i + ')').fadeOut();
}, 300);
```

Delayed execution in a loop is best done with an [*interval*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval). Once you have reached your terminating condition, you just clear it.

Comment: You're the man, thanks. I knew my syntax was improper however, it's late and im tired and I just cant seem to remember these kinds of things well :) Thank you

Comment: @deceze: I believe this will miss the first `article` because of the prefix decrement operator, or the `<= 0`. It should be `i-- <=0` or `--i < 0`

Comment: @Andrew Ah, you're right. There was also an off-by-one problem for the first iteration (classic length vs. 0-index)...

Comment: More specifically, it will miss the 0th element. Additionally, it starts with 1 after the last element. To fix this swap the places of `--i` and `i` so you have `i <= 0` and `$('#aHolder article:eq(' + (--i) + ')').fadeOut();`

Comment: @gereeter It should be working now. I haven't had my morning coffee yet, so if you can still spot an off-by-one issue here, please feel free to edit. :)

Comment: I submitted one last edit to your code changing the `i--` to a `--i` so that the code wouldn't try to fade the -1st element.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 
  $('#bottomNav a:eq(0)').click(function(){
  
  var articles = $('#aHolder article').length,
   arts  = articles - 1;
      i        = 0,
      interval = setInterval(function () {
          $('#aHolder article:eq('+arts+')').fadeOut();
          if (--arts == -1) {
             clearInterval(interval);
          }
       }, 100);
  
  });
 
 });

Comment: I posted the script above just so you can see what I went with. Might be kind of unessicary how I handled it.

Comment: @gereeter Your suggestion would miss the 1st element, wouldn't it?

Comment: @deceze No because even when you clear the interval, the code continues running. So when your code runs, `i--` will eventually hit 0. Then `i` will be -1. So your code runs on an extra element. By using `--i` the problem is fixed because it hits 0 when `i` does.

Comment: @deceze You can also fix your code by keeping `i--` and inserting a `return` statement after `clearInterval`.

Comment: @gereeter Right, the `return` was what was missing!

Comment: @deceze Quick question about JavaScript structure in general, how is a function that is defined inside a variable executing?

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I suggest you open a new question for that with proper example.

Comment: Well the Variable is interval and it has the function, but some how it runs when you click.. I did not know that variables could be executed as functions. Perhaps my understanding of Javascript is too low.

Comment: @Steve No, `interval` "is" not the function. Please read the documentation about intervals I linked to. But yes, functions can be passed around like variables and variables that are functions can be called in Javascript.